# Admin Page access

Tags: wp-admin, user-access

There is a admin page that gives me this error on the page itself when I try to access it: “Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.”

In the console it logs: “Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()”

the page: site/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=menu_editor

I staged the site on localhost, this same error occurs there as well.

Here is what I tried so far:
-conflict test with plugins
-making sure the directories have the 755 and files have the 644 permissions

Comment: `/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=menu_editor` is not a valid URL in core WP, so if that ever worked it was probably related to a third-party plugin or theme.

Answer (score 0):

As i can not allowed to comment, I post it here:
Please Make sure when you are login to wp-admin, in usermeta table you have a role of 'administration' in $prefix->capabilities  meta_key.

Because this Message comes when you try login, that user has different role other than admin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My bad if I was being unclear. But it was a specific admin page that I was trying to access, hence the URL.

Turns out another admin had restricted that page to themselves before I was around. So only their account could access it.

Bit of miscommunication due to working remotely.